# Serilog logger configuration by SourceContext

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core, serilog

I am trying to implement serilog in a little sample-project. I´ve did the following so far:

- Create new ASP.NET Core Web Application (MVC)
- Install-Package Serilog.AspNetCore
- Install-Package Serilog.Sinks.File
- Install-Package Serilog.Formatting.Compact
- Follow [this](https://nblumhardt.com/2017/08/use-serilog/) blogpost
- Try to follow [this](https://nblumhardt.com/2016/11/ilogger-beginscope/) blogpost

My question:

Is there a possibility to configure two different loggers, based on CategoryName (in my case "MyLogger")? I want this logger to use a different file, than my default-logger. In my happy-world-fantasy it would look like:

```
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.File(new CompactJsonFormatter(), @"C:\temp\standardLog.txt")
            .WriteTo.File(new CompactJsonFormatter(), @"C:\temp\specialLog.txt").Filter.ByIncludingOnly(x => x.SourceContext("MySpecialLogger")
            .CreateLogger();
```

And if I create a new Logger `var logger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger("MySpecialLogger");` the logs will be safed in my specialLog.txt-file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need *Serilog.Sinks.Map* for this.

```
dotnet add <PROJECT> package Serilog.Sinks.Map -v 1.0.0-dev-00012
```

Then:

```
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Debug()
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .WriteTo.Map("SourceContext", null, (sc, wt) =>
            wt.File(new CompactJsonFormatter(), sc == "MySpecialLogger" ?
                @"C:\temp\specialLog.txt" :
                @"C:\temp\standardLog.txt"))
        .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: First of all: Thanks for having time for my question!! Regarding your answer: The conditional operator fails (compiler-error only assignment, call (...) can be used as a statement).. This param is not valid: `Action<string, LoggerSinkConfiguration> configure = (x, wt) => x == "" ? wt.File("") : wt.File("")` ; - but I really like the Map-approach.. Any other idea?

Comment: Great! If I use RollingFile-Sink I have everything I wanted :) Thanks a lot!!! But there is still some unexpected behaviour: MySpecialLogger works as expected. But if I use the File-Sink, my StandardLogger only outputs "Starting Web Host". If I use RollingFile, i get 2 log files (standard-{date}.txt and standard-{date}_001.txt) where the 001-log contains my messages and the other only contains the startup-message. If I remove the `Log.Information("Starting web host")`  -Call, everything works as expected...

Comment: Ah! Sorry, the answer's not 100% correct, I'll update it.